# How to change Logo Company size

Tags: html, css, odoo, odoo-10

I want to change Logo company size in Sale Order and Custommer Invoice, I code with this but haven't changed that logo size.

here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="co_report_saleorder_document">
    <t t-call="report.external_layout">
        <t t-set="docs" t-value="docs.with_context({'lang':docs.partner_id.lang})" />

        <!-- Multicompany -->
        <t t-if="not o and doc">
            <t t-set="o" t-value="doc"/>
        </t>
        <t t-if="o and 'company_id' in o">
            <t t-set="company" t-value="o.company_id"></t>
        </t>
        <t t-if="not o or not 'company_id' in o">
            <t t-set="company" t-value="res_company"></t>
        </t>

        <div class="header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row zero_min_height">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</template>


<template id="report_saleorder">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="docs">
            <t t-call="sale.fal_report_saleorder_document" t-lang="docs.partner_id.lang"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

<report
    string="Cetak Sales"
    id="co_view_sale"
    model="sale.order"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="co_sale_report.co_report_saleorder_document"
    file="co_sale_report.co_report_saleorder_document"
/>

</odoo>
```

I have add code in style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;" but haven't change. somebody can help me?

Comment: Why did you tag this question Python?

Comment: Have you tried applying this cream? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgcX0y1Nzhs

Answer (score 5):

You can not directly change into external layout. First you need to change header layout from the report module by inherit a template.

```
<template id="external_layout_header_inherited" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header" primary="True">
<xpath expr="//img" position="replace">
    <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" height='150' width='200' />
</xpath></template>
```

hope this is help....

Comment: I try with this, but not changed. <template id="co_report_external_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='row']" position="replace">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img t-att-src="'static/src/img/L.png'" style="max-height: 45px;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below width block css

```
style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; display: block;"
```

Comment: I try with this, but still not yet change

Comment: try specifying width and height also

Comment: I have error this = Error to render compiling AST
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Template: 1400
Path: /templates/t/t/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/img
Node: <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'/static/src/img/lg.png' % company.logo" style="max-width: 500px; max-height: 350px; display: block;" data-oe-id="1400" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/t[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/img[1]"/>

Comment: Give width height in style attr only